# How can I use JQuery to create an efficient method for Next and Prev buttons to show/hide Sections of a single HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a single HTML file comprised of several sections and I need to be able to display one Section at a time. Each section will have Next and Previous buttons at the bottom which will show the next Section and hide the section currently in focus.

Originally I was using a very simple method to achieve achieve this:

```
<section id="Page1" class="page" style="display:none">
  <p>Content of page 1</p>
  <h3><span onclick="show('Page2');">Next</span></h3>
</section>
<section id="Page2" class="page" style="display:none">
  <p>Content of page 2</p>
  <h3><span onclick="show('Page1');">Previous</span></h3>
  <h3><span onclick="show('Page3');">Next</span></h3>
</section>
<section id="Page3" class="page" style="display:none">
  <p>Content of page 3</p>
  <h3><span onclick="show('Page2');">Previous</span></h3>
</section>
```

However, since the number of Sections will fluctuate, and the very first and last section will always have the same content, I want to make it easy for the person using this HTML template to simply delete all unneeded sections in between without having to update the IDs targeted by the Prev/Next button code.

Here's my Fiddle: [Next Previous Button Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2ud1hLn/)

I started some JQuery that ALMOST works (beneath the //Next Prev Buttons comment). I'm using :focus, which means it's only targeting the Span that contains the button, but I can't figure out the selector for the button's parent Section tag.

Thanks in advance for your time. :)

Comment: Is it a requirement to use JQuery for this?, or  you accept any kind solution that makes easy the work with HTML?

Comment: Several issues with your fiddle. Here is one that does not give errors https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qsr82gb1/

Comment: Why do you hide the button when clicked?

Comment: The button is being hidden when clicked because currently it's being targeted by :Focus. I don't want the Next/Prev buttons to be hidden.

Also, I'm open to non-JQuery solutions, but prefer Javascript (or libraries) as I will be plugging my finished code into Litmos (an LMS that seems almost randomly to accept some code and override others).

Comment: onclick="showPrev()" and onclick="showNext() all need to be removed

Comment: Use next.toggle(no previous sections) and prev.toggle(no next sections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:focus` selector won't select your `<span>` because it [isn't a typically "tabbable" element](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/). Since the `<span>` is the element that was clicked to trigger your click handler, you can access it through `this` (or `$(this)` if you want the jQuery version).

`$.next` [only searches *siblings* of the selected element](https://api.jquery.com/next/). Since the next section isn't a sibling of your `<span>`, `$.next` won't find it. You'll need to find the parent `<section>` with [`$.closest('section')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and move to the next section from there.

You're using `$(this).hide();`, which only hides the clicked element. Again, use `$(this).closest('section')` to find the entire section and hide that.

With the click handlers defined in your JavaScript, you don't need the `onclick` attributes in your HTML. Remove them.

Putting it all together:

```js
$('.pageNext').on('click', function showNext() {
  // cache DOM lookups when possible
  const $currentSection = $(this).closest('section');
  $currentSection.next('section').show();
  $currentSection.hide();
});

$('.pagePrev').on('click', function showPrev() {
  const $currentSection = $(this).closest('section');
  $currentSection.prev('section').show();
  $currentSection.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="Page1" class="page" style="">
  <p>Content of page 1</p>
  <h3><span class="pageNext">Next</span></h3>
</section>
<section id="Page2" class="page" style="display:none">
  <p>Content of page 2</p>
  <h3><span class="pagePrev">Previous</span></h3>
  <h3><span class="pageNext">Next</span></h3>
</section>
<section id="Page3" class="page" style="display:none">
  <p>Content of page 3</p>
  <h3><span class="pagePrev">Previous</span></h3>
  <h3><span class="pageNext">Next</span></h3>
</section>
<section id="Page4" class="page" style="display:none">
  <p>Content of page 4</p>
  <h3><span class="pagePrev">Previous</span></h3>
  <h3><span class="pageNext">Next</span></h3>
</section>
<section id="Page5" class="page" style="display:none">
  <p>Content of page 5</p>
  <h3><span class="pagePrev">Previous</span></h3>
  <h3><span class="pageNext">Next</span></h3>
</section>
<section id="Page6" class="page" style="display:none">
  <p>Content of page 6</p>
  <h3><span class="pagePrev">Previous</span></h3>
  <h3><span class="pageNext">Next</span></h3>
</section>
<section id="Page7" class="page" style="display:none">
  <p>Content of page 7</p>
  <h3><span class="pagePrev">Previous</span></h3>
</section>
```

This also translates easily, if more verbosely, to vanilla JavaScript:

```
// $('.pageNext').on('click', function showNext() {
document.querySelectorAll('.pageNext').forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function showNext(event) {
//  const $currentSection = $(this).closest('section');
    const currentSection = event.target.closest('section');
//  $currentSection.next('section').show();
//  (not a direct translation but it works since you don't have
//  non-section siblings)
    currentSection.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
    // or previousElementSibling for $.prev
//  $currentSection.hide();
    currentSection.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your well reasoned reply! I'm new to JQuery and therefore don't know the nuances yet (like that span wasn't a tabbable element). Not only did you correct my code but you helped explain where I was going wrong. Keep kicking butt, AuxTaco. :D

Comment: @CodeLyfe Just added the vanilla equivalent for completeness.

Comment: Thank you :) I hope you have an awesome day ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

Change your functions to this:

```
//Next Prev Buttons

$('.pageNext').on('click', function showNext(){
    //$(":focus").next('section').show();
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
$(this).parent().parent().next().show();
});

$('.pagePrev').on('click', function showPrev(){
    //$(":focus").next('section').show();
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
$(this).parent().parent().prev().show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I knew that this or :focus would allow me to access the parent somehow, just wasn't sure on the proper syntax. I'm used to CSS so I think that's getting me in trouble. Thank you!